# Error en Java Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java

Tengo como código:

```
//Get e-mail server 
@Override
public String getType(){
   return(String) typeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
}
```

Me aparece error en esas lineas y no sé qué podría ser, aparte de que en el primero (En "get e-mail server") me pide poner el `Override` y cuando lo pongo me pide quitarlo y es el único error que marca, ¿alguna idea de por qué sera?

Comment: con que rellenas el combo, con objetos del tipo String o con otros objetos???

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano utilizo tipo String, estoy realizando un gestor de correo electronico

Comment: Con el código que has puesto cuesta mucho ver lo que te pasa (parece que está bien) aunque prueba a poner returntypeComboBox.getSelectedItem().ToString(); Si esto no te funciona tendrás que poner más código para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano el error me aparece en ´public String getType(){´
me aparece como "getType() is ConnectDialog cannot override getType() in Wondow return type String in not compatible with Type" y "Add Override Anotation" como solución me aparece añadir un Override pero me sigue marcando error y me aparece como error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

Comment: Mira esto, es lo que te dice @SJuan76 aunque menos extendido https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9064889/type-error-in-java-7

Answer (score 0):

De los comentarios:

> el error me aparece en ´public String getType(){´ me aparece como "getType() is ConnectDialog cannot override getType() in Wondow return type String in not compatible with Type" y "Add Override Anotation"

Son dos cosas diferentes.

Esto viene porque estás sobreescribiendo un método de la clase padre (o, a partir de Java 7, implementando un método de una interficie).

El "Add Override Annotation" es solo un consejo; para asegurarte de que "marcas" para el compilador que el método implementa un método de la clase padre/interficie<sup>1</sup>. No tiene nada que ver con el error.

El error es que, al implementar el método, lo estás haciendo de forma que defines un tipo de retorno que no tiene nada que ver con el método original. Por ejemplo, igual el método original tiene una signatura `public int getType()`. Como no hay conversión automática posible de `String` a `int`, no te permite esa definición<sup>2</sup>.

Solución: Haz que el tipo de retorno concuerde con el definido en la superclase/interficie.

---

<sup>1</sup>Lo que hace esto es que fuerza al compilador a comprobar que, efectivamente, el método existe en la superclase/interficie. De esa forma, si cambia la signatura del método ahí, te avisa para que cambies la de la subclase, o te avisa si has escrito mal la signatura.

<sup>2</sup>Si en la superclase/interficie hubieras definido el método como `public Object getType()` entonces no habría error, ya que un `String` es una subclase de `Object` y se podría asignar el `String` allí donde se use `getType()`.

Comment: Intenté ponerlo así como me lo pusiste el ´public Object getType()´ pero me sigue apareciendo el mismo error

Comment: A ver, tienes que editar tu pregunta para mostrar el código de la declaración del método en la superclase/interface. Lo que escribí yo es un ejemplo, no tengo telepatía para saber la declaración del método que estás implementando.