# Error en Java con Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo como código

```
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;


import javax.swing.*;


//Esta clase muestra un cuadro de diálogo para introducir Servidor.

public class ConnectDialog extends JDialog {

// Estos son los tipos de servidor de correo electrónico.
private static final String[] TYPES = {"pop3", "imap"};

// Cuadro combinado para tipos de servidor de correo electrónico.
private JComboBox typeComboBox;

// Servidor, nombre de usuario y campos de texto del servidor SMTP.
private JTextField serverTextField, usernameTextField;
private JTextField smtpServerTextField;

// Campo de texto de contraseña.
private JPasswordField passwordField;

// Constructor para el diálogo.
public ConnectDialog(Frame parent) {
    // Llame a super constructor, especificando que el diálogo es modal.
    super(parent, true);

    // Establecer el título del diálogo.
    setTitle("Connect");

    // Manejar eventos de cierre.
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            actionCancel();
        }
    });

    // Configuración del panel de configuración.
    JPanel settingsPanel = new JPanel();
    settingsPanel.setBorder(
            BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Connection Settings"));
    GridBagConstraints constraints;
    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    settingsPanel.setLayout(layout);
    JLabel typeLabel = new JLabel("Type:");
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
    layout.setConstraints(typeLabel, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(typeLabel);
    typeComboBox = new JComboBox(TYPES);
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    constraints.weightx = 1.0D;
    layout.setConstraints(typeComboBox, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(typeComboBox);
    JLabel serverLabel = new JLabel("Server:");
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
    layout.setConstraints(serverLabel, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(serverLabel);
    serverTextField = new JTextField(25);
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    constraints.weightx = 1.0D;
    layout.setConstraints(serverTextField, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(serverTextField);
    JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 0);
    layout.setConstraints(usernameLabel, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(usernameLabel);
    usernameTextField = new JTextField();
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 0, 5);
    constraints.weightx = 1.0D;
    layout.setConstraints(usernameTextField, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(usernameTextField);
    JLabel passwordLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 0);
    layout.setConstraints(passwordLabel, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(passwordLabel);
    passwordField = new JPasswordField();
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    constraints.weightx = 1.0D;
    layout.setConstraints(passwordField, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(passwordField);
    JLabel smtpServerLabel = new JLabel("SMTP Server:");
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 0);
    layout.setConstraints(smtpServerLabel, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(smtpServerLabel);
    smtpServerTextField = new JTextField(25);
    constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraints.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
    constraints.weightx = 1.0D;
    layout.setConstraints(smtpServerTextField, constraints);
    settingsPanel.add(smtpServerTextField);

    // Configuración del panel de botones.
    JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    JButton connectButton = new JButton("Connect");
    connectButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            actionConnect();
        }
    });
    buttonsPanel.add(connectButton);
    JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
    cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            actionCancel();
        }
    });
    buttonsPanel.add(cancelButton);

    // Añadir paneles para mostrar.
    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    getContentPane().add(settingsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Diálogo de tamaño a los componentes.
    pack();

    // Centro de diálogo sobre la aplicación.
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
}

// Validar la configuración de la conexión y cerrar el cuadro de diálogo.
private void actionConnect() {
    if (serverTextField.getText().trim().length() < 1
            || usernameTextField.getText().trim().length() < 1
            || passwordField.getPassword().length < 1
            || smtpServerTextField.getText().trim().length() < 1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
                "One or more settings is missing.",
                "Missing Setting(s)", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    // Cerrar diálogo.
    dispose();
}

// Cancelar la conexión y salir del programa.
private void actionCancel() {
    System.exit(0);
}

     //Obtener servidor de correo electrónico
public String getType(){
   return(String) typeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
}

// Obtener servidor de correo electrónico
public String getServer() {
    return serverTextField.getText();
}

// Obtener un nombre de usuario de correo electrónico.
public String getUsername() {
    return usernameTextField.getText();
}

// Obtener contraseña de correo electrónico.
public String getPassword() {
    return new String(passwordField.getPassword());
}

// Obtener correo electrónico del servidor SMTP.
public String getSmtpServer() {
    return smtpServerTextField.getText();
}
}
```

Me aparece error en esas lineas 166 y no sé qué podría ser, aparte de que en el "Obtener servidor de correo electronico" me pide poner el Override y cuando lo pongo me pide quitarlo y es el único error que me marca en el netbeans, alguna idea de por qué sera?

Comment: Hola. podrias aclarar cual es la linea 166?

Comment: Claro, es ápartir del ´public String getType(){
       return(String) typeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    }´

Comment: En ocasiones ese error me ha salido porque no esta bien instalado java. Como por ejemplo que solo instalaron jre y no jdk o cosas así. Puedes revisar si java esta instalado correctamente? Te puedes ayudar con mi respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/79287/por-que-eclipse-me-marca-este-error/79290#79290
También tienes que asegurarte de que netbeans este encontrando correctamente a java. Por ultimo, una vez hecho todo esto crea un nuevo proyecto y ve pegando tu código en el nuevo. A veces los proyectos se corrompen. Te comento esto porque no alcanzo a ver nada raro en el código.

Comment: Hola Chivo, Pregunta relacionada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/93530/error-en-java-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-runtimeexception

Comment: @abrahamhs Ya chequé que tuviera bien instalado el netbeans, ya he corrido diferentes programas hechos y no había tenido este problema

Comment: @Jorgesys lo que intento hacer es un gestor de correos electronicos, esta clase es donde se conecta todo, sólo me marca error en ese médoto.

Comment: Me parece que lo que estas haciendo con el public String getType es sobrescribir el metodo getType de la clase JDialog la cual hereda de la clase windows docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/… de la cual extiendes tu clase, creo que deberias intentar con otro metodo o nombrarlo de otra forma

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que como heredas de `JDialog` estas sobre escribiendo un método de `Windows` como lo señala el error.
[image: Popup Netbeans]
[image: Clase Windows]

Cuando usas la solución propuesta por **Netbeans** realmente no arreglas el problema pues no puedes sobreescribir ese método retornando un tipo de dato diferente.

La solución es cambiar el nombre al método quizas por:

```
public String getProtocolType() {
        return (String) typeComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    }
```